# Is there a way for screen readers to read out <ol type="a">

Tags: html, css, drupal, accessibility

Currently repurposing a whole of content in the 1000's for a drupal website.They contain ordered lists of alpha type.

example:

a. foo

b. bar

c. char

The screen reader doesnt read the "a." or any of the alpha dot points.Currently im resorting to creating 2 span tags, one is for the screen reader hidden from the display and the other hidden to the screen reader.

```
<li>
    <span class="accessbility-hide-element">B, list item text</span>
    <span aria-hidden="true">list item text</span></li>
</li>
```

Is there an easier away? As this will take a long time, cheers.

Comment: I never have had any problem with any screen reader and ordered lists of types a, A, i and I. It has always worked well for ages. Can you post an example page and tell with which screen reader and browser you have tested ?

Comment: What is the CSS like on the `<li>`? Can you paste that into your question, especially if there are any `:before` pseudo selectors.

Comment: Actually that is stated in the title: Mernlin used the `type` attribute, which is obsolete, plus the attributes value doesn't seem to be right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a very old way to style your list, which might be the reason your screen reader is not picking up on it.

The correct, modern way to style your list is by means of CSS:

```
<ol style="list-style-type: lower-alpha">
```

Possible values for your case are `lower-alpha` and `lower-latin`, see [list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type)

I tested on Windows 10 with NVDA and Firefox, and it's reading "a. foo". Also the Accessibility Tab in Firefox Developer Tools is confirming this exposed text.